# Why can dired-do-shell-command not operate on '.' or '..'?

Tags: emacs

Using `emacs` on `cygwin`, one shell command I use very often from `dired` buffers using <kbd>!</kbd> bound to `dired-do-shell-command` is `cygstart`, .e.g to open a Word document or a Visual Studio project or whatever.

But hitting `!` on current directory entry, `.`, results in error `Cannot operate on`.' or `..'`.

I wanted to find out before I bypass it and allow the command to be run on current and parent directories. **Is there any reason for this restriction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This restriction has been lifted since the question was asked.

In the current stable release of Emacs (24.3), you can use `dired-do-shell-command` on `.` and `..`

Comment: Thank you for following up, works as you describe on my cygwin Emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 1):

`dired-do-shell-command` calls `dired-get-filename`.

If you take a look on the dired-get-filename doc you will see

```
(dired-get-filename &optional LOCALP NO-ERROR-IF-NOT-FILEP)
```

> In Dired, return name of file mentioned on this line.
>
> ...
>
> Optional arg NO-ERROR-IF-NOT-FILEP means treat `.' and`
>   ..' as regular filenames and return nil if no filename on this line.
>   Otherwise, an error occurs in these cases.

`dired-get-filename` is called without `NO-ERROR-IF-NOT-FILEP` argument

Comment: And that is my question...why is `dired-get-filename` is called without `NO-ERROR-IF-NOT-FILEP` argument?

Comment: Because it's called from dired-get-marked-files. This function is often used to copy/delete/etc marked files which makes no sense for . and .. files

Comment: I can't agree with that logic, though you may be right. Why punish `dired-do-shell-command` for sometimes-convenience of copy/delete marked files.